# Failed to get Thumbnails

Tags: android

I'm trying to get Thumbnail bitmaps using the following code, but it failed and threw the error below. How can I resolve this error?

**Code**

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);

// I get id like 
String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " desc");

id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
```

**Error**

```
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355): miniThumbDataFile: IOException(rw) for: /storage/emulated/0/.thumbnails/.thumbdata-6.0_18, try read only mode
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/.thumbnails/.thumbdata-6.0_18: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:453)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:118)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.media.MiniThumbFile.miniThumbDataFile(MiniThumbFile.java:174)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.media.MiniThumbFile.getMagic(MiniThumbFile.java:211)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.provider.MediaStore$InternalThumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:653)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Thumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:1152)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at com.dvlee.androidtest.util.LocalImageBitmapUtil.getThumbnail(LocalImageBitmapUtil.java:140)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at com.dvlee.androidtest.util.BitmapCacheHelper$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapCacheHelper.java:118)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at com.dvlee.androidtest.util.BitmapCacheHelper$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapCacheHelper.java:78)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:437)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     ... 14 more
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355): Got exception when reading thumbnail, id = 307318, disk full or mount read-only? class java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355): miniThumbDataFile: IOException(rw) for: /storage/emulated/0/.thumbnails/.thumbdata-6.0_18, try read only mode
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/.thumbnails/.thumbdata-6.0_18: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:453)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:118)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.media.MiniThumbFile.miniThumbDataFile(MiniThumbFile.java:174)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.media.MiniThumbFile.getMagic(MiniThumbFile.java:211)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.provider.MediaStore$InternalThumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:653)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Thumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:1152)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at com.dvlee.androidtest.util.LocalImageBitmapUtil.getThumbnail(LocalImageBitmapUtil.java:140)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at com.dvlee.androidtest.util.BitmapCacheHelper$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapCacheHelper.java:118)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at com.dvlee.androidtest.util.BitmapCacheHelper$BitmapWorkerTask.doInBackground(BitmapCacheHelper.java:78)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:437)
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355):     ... 14 more
E/MiniThumbFile( 6355): Got exception when reading thumbnail, id = 307316, disk full or mount read-only? class java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html).

```
final int THUMBSIZE = 64;

Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), 
                    THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```